# Accessing SQL Server Express 2005 database via 2008 64bit SSMS

Tags: 64-bit, ssms, sql-server-2005-express

I have a 64bit Vista laptop. Initally, I tried to Install a 64bit version SQL Server Express 2005 on my computer, but no matter what I tried, only the 32bit version seemed to work...so that is what got installed.

The 32bit SQL Server Express 2005 was working fine, but recently I installed a 64bit version of SQL Server Express 2008 - with all the tools and features. During the install, it recognized my 2005 database correctly, but it forced me to uninstall my 2005 SSMS, before I could install the 2008 version.

That is fine, but the problem is that when I try and access an existing 2005 database through  the 2008 SSMS, it gives me the following message:

"The database planboard is not accessible (Object Explorer)"

--where "planboard" is the name of my 2005 database.

Does anyone have an idea about how to get around this error/problem?

--Thanks
Mike C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after doing a little Google research. My sa password for my 2005 instance, was different from my 2008 instance. Further, although I could login to the 2005 instance using Windows Authentication, I could not access the planboard database with it. After logging in specifically with my old 2005 sa password, I was able to see the database.  I then found that the 2005 instance did not have my windows username as a login with rights to the planboard database.

I am not quite sure why it worked before, and then didn't work after the 2008 install...but after specifically entering my Windows username in as a SQL Server login to the 2005 instance, and giving it rights to the planboard database...I can now login use Windows Authentication to access the 2005 database as well.

I thought it was a 32 vs 64-bit issue, but it was just a security issue.